# Is Every DCFL has LR(0),SLR(1) and LALR(1) parser??? please answer my question

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I know that grammars parsed by parsers is of the powers LR(0)<Slr(1)<LALR(1)<CLR(1)...
But my doubt is ..IS every dcfl(Language) have an lr(0) ,lalr(1),slr(1) parser???

Comment: Grammars are not "generated by parsers". But it is true that every deterministic language has an SLR(1) grammar (which is also an LALR(1) and CLR(1) grammar.) If the language also has the orefix property (for example, if every valid sentence has an endmarker), then it also has ab LR(0) grammar.

Comment: Am sorry edited now....So it means for every dterminstic language there is lalr(1) and slr(1)???

Comment: Yes. An SLR(1) grammar is LALR(1) .